# Meteor.js Cordova App Submission Error: missing 57x57 icon

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

I tried submitting/validating a Cordova app built from Meteor.js 1.0, but during the process it gives an error

[image]

Here's my `mobile-config.js` copied from the `localmarket` example app:

```
App.icons({
  // iOS
  'iphone': 'resources/icons/icon-60x60.png',
  'iphone_2x': 'resources/icons/icon-60x60@2x.png',
  'ipad': 'resources/icons/icon-72x72.png',
  'ipad_2x': 'resources/icons/icon-72x72@2x.png',

  // Android
  'android_ldpi': 'resources/icons/icon-36x36.png',
  'android_mdpi': 'resources/icons/icon-48x48.png',
  'android_hdpi': 'resources/icons/icon-72x72.png',
  'android_xhdpi': 'resources/icons/icon-96x96.png'
});
```

How should the missing 57x57 icon be included?

Comment: Looks like a bug? Submit it to GitHub

Comment: @imslavko which repo should I open an issue at?

Comment: meteor/meteor probably

Comment: damn it, same issue here!!

Comment: Meteor Github issue here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3153

Answer (score 0):

Currently the mobile-config.js file does not have a key for the 57x57 icon. I'm sure that will be updated soon. For now add it manually.

Open your project in xcode and add the icon to the file directory under Resources > icons with the name icon.png

An even better option is to select the Images.xcassets folder under Resources. From there you can add all missing icons. This way will also save the icons for future versions.

[image: folder]

Answer (score 0):

If you run your app on iOS >= 7.0, change the deployment target.

In Project > General > Deployment Info - Deployment target, choose 7.0